# How can I see the matched results of a configured Extractor on an Input in Graylog

Tags: graylog2

I tried to add an Extractor for Key/Value Pairs in a Graylog Input according to http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.3/pages/extractors.html#automatically-extract-all-key-value-pairs.

I did set up the Extractor like in the example and can also see that on the Manage Extractors tab if i click Details on my Extractor that there were hits for the extractor.

But none of the Messages the extractor matched are to be seen in any of my streams. So I did not manage to see the extracted output of any of my matches so far. Needs anything else to be done in order for extractors to work?

[image: Extractor Configuration]

[image: Configured Extractor with Hits]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So nothing needs to be done in order to see the results, the problem was that my extractor threw a parsing exception that I did not notice.